How do I get this Github Project to compile without a SLN file?
I'm trying to compile the project here: https://github.com/boozallen/raptor
I'm using visual studio, but I noticed there is no solution file, and even when I try to manually compile there is a modsim.h file that is missing, but can't be found on the internet (let alone on the github project page). Any insight into how I can get this to full compile would be much appreciated.

Contact the author of the project. We can't invent the missing header file; you'll need to find out from the author where you can find it.

Clone the repository
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/boozallen/raptor.git


Hi, how does this get added to the VS clone that already exists?
